# Visual Studio JIT Debugger loads extremely slow, 30 seconds

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, f#

When I run a .Net program that executes

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()
```

that should bring up the JIT debugger. Here is what happens on my machine:

An alert titled "Machine Debug Manager" comes up, explaining its command line options. Ok, so this is mdm.exe, but could'nt it be silent?

The real issue comes now: Quite exactly **30 seconds** later the Visual Studio JIT Debugger selection dialog comes up.

Since procmon does not show registry or file system activity within these 30 seconds I assume some timeout occurs (due to the 30 seconds length). Procmon also shows that vsjitdebugger.exe fires up at the very beginning, so the 30 seconds apparently are in issue of vsjitdebugger and not of mdm.

Anybody has an idea how I can get rid of the delay?

Comment: Could the debugger possibly try to fetch symbol files from an remote share that is offline?

Comment: No, that happens *after* the selection.  You should not see mdm.exe, the timeout quacks like a networking timeout although it is a bit too short.  Your machine is sick, you need the geek squad, not a programmer.  Use the kind of troubleshooting techniques that Mark Russinovich describes in his blog.

Comment: well, did not read the whole blog, but your hint on mdm pointed in the right direction. checked my win7 notebook and there is just no mdm.exe. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

removed "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7DEBUG\mdm.exe"

which apparently is something old. regsvr32 /u mdm.exe failed, so might cleanup the COM registry by hand.

JIT starts immediately now.